# JQuery: One function between two sites. How to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, hyperlink

I have a question. my example_1.html looks like this:

> ```
> <main role="main">   <div class="container">
> <div class="card">
>   <div class="card-header">
>     <ul class="nav">
>       <li class="nav-item">
>         <a id="Linkitem1" class="Linkitem" href="#" role="button" title="">item1</a>
>       </li>
>       <li class="nav-item">
>         <a id="Linkitem2" class="Linkitem" href="#" role="button" title="">item2</a>
>       </li>
>       <li class="nav-item">
>         <a id="Linkitem3" class="Linkitem" href="#" role="button" title="">item3</a>
>       </li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>
>   <!--Content item1-->
>   <div id="item1" class="item card-body" data-parent="#card-content">
>     <h5 class="card-title">title for item 1</h5>
>     <p class="card-text">content item 1.</p>
>   </div>
>
>   <!--content item 2-->
>   <div id="item2" class="item card-body" data-parent="#card-content">
>     <h5 class="card-title">title item 2</h5>
>     <p class="card-text">content item 2</p> </div>
>     <!--content 3-->
>     <div id="item3" class="item card-body" data-parent="#card-content">
>       <h5 class="card-title">title item 3</h5>
>       <p class="card-text">content item 3</p>
>     </div>
>   </div> </main>
> ```

And script.js is looking like this:

> $(".Linkitem").click(function(){      event.preventDefault();   let
>   dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
>   $('.item[data-id='+dataId+']').fadeIn(2500);
>   $('.item:not([data-id='+dataId+'])').hide();
>        $('.Linkitem[data-id='+dataId+']').addClass("active btn-warning");
>   $('.Linkitem:not([data-id='+dataId+'])').removeClass("active
>   btn-warning");
>        });

Now I would like to combine example_1.html with my example_2.html, which has this content:

```
<button><a href="">button1</a></button> 
<button><a href="">button2</a></button> 
<button><a href="">button3</a></button>
```

And would like to follow thing:

If I have clicked on example_2.html on the button1, then it has to open a new window(example_1.html and its like, I have clicked on "Linkitem1".

Then button2, like I have clicked on Linkitem2 and button3 like Linkitem3.

Am a beginner and therefore I need help. How should to write javascript code to do this? Someone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass some parameter in link when opening new window.

So when your example_2.html would look like this ( `target="_blank"` opens new window but I think you have already know that)

```
<a href="example_1.html#Linkitem1" target="_blank">button1</a>
<a href="example_1.html#Linkitem2" target="_blank">button2</a> 
<a href="example_1.html#Linkitem3" target="_blank">button3</a>
```

Assuming you attach `js` for `example_1.html` you can then read it like that

```
if(window.location.hash == '#Linkitem1'){
   // do something with linkitem1
}
else if (window.location.hash == '#Linkitem2`){
 // do smth with linkitem2
}
...
```

of course there is a way to make it more generic but I want to give only the idea.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you need to remember that using `#` leads scroll to go to `div` with that `id`. You could use `!#` to avoid that instead of `#`

Answer (score 0):

you have to add data-id tag first in order to run you script

```
$('.item[data-id='+dataId+']')
```